Hardware acceleration for the Android Emulator - AEHD not working (STOPPED state) on the laptop with Windows 11 Home
I bought an Asus Rog Strix Laptop which comes with Windows 11 Home.
I want to use it for both Android development and gaming.
So based on the docs I checked the status of Android Emulator hypervisor driver (AEHD):
SERVICE_NAME: aehd
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 31  (0x1f)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

Docs says that if I have something like:
// from docs example:
SERVICE_NAME: aehd
       ...
       STATE              : 1  STOPPED
       WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 4294967201 (0xffffffa1)
       ...

then

The following error message means either that virtualization extension
is not enabled in your BIOS or that Hyper-V is not disabled

Intel VT and VT-d are enabled:

Windows Task Manager:

Hyper-V is disabled and not installed at all:

(actually it should be Hyper-V but it's not even in the list because of Windows Home)
and Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V prints nothing which means it's disabled:

It seems Hyper-V is not supported by Windows 11 Home though but I guess it should not effect AEHD support? So what can be an issue here? Or do I actually need Window 11 Pro to make AEHD work as well?

Actually there are more things we have to disable:

Virtual Machine Platform
Windows Hypervisor Platform
Windows Sandbox
Core Isolation
Credential Guard

I have disabled Virtual Machine Platform and Core Isolation (in Windows Defender / Device Security)
And now it works:
SERVICE_NAME: aehd
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0



From Android docs:


The following worked for me:

disable Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor and HypervisorPlatform via PowerShell:
Run PowerSell as admin, execute both commands and reboot:
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform

Disable device guard as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows
read carefully "Disabling Device Guard" paragraph.
reboot and accept both choices.

check acceleration status:
PATH_TO_ANDOID_EMULATOR/emulator.exe -accel-check
Output should looks like this:
accel:
0
AEHD (version 2.2) is installed and usable.
accel


